# German single word for "currently watching" in multimedia interfaces

Tags: single-word-request

Is there a single german word for "watching" as in a movie that is currently being watched?

I can only think of sentences such as:

- Wird gerade abgespielt/angeschaut.
- Spielt gerade.

I am wondering if there is just a single german word that could be used in a textbox displaying the current status (media is being played or movie is currently stopped) of a movie/film/clip.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Generally, a movie is *being watched*, that's why the corresponding German phrase *wird gerade angeschaut* is correct. But the movie cannot itself be *watching*, thus it doesn't make sense to look for a German single word for *watching* in this context. Maybe you rather mean that someone *is watching* a movie. But then the German phrase is *jemand schaut (gerade) einen Film*, where *is watching* simply corresponds to *schaut (gerade)*.

Comment: @tofro interpreted my question how I had it in mind. See the accepted answer.

Comment: Are you wondering what single German word you would put in a textfield showing whether the movie is currently being watched?

Comment: Exactly! I'll update my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am interpreting your question as "What would the GUI of a VCR show for a title that is currently being watched".

You wouldn't normally express that with "anschauen", but rather in active form with "laufen".

> Läuft [gerade]: Star Trek Enterprise
>
> nächstes: Babylon 5

Comment: This is what I had in mind. E.g. you need to display a list of videos in a GUI out of which one is currently being watched. I was looking for a label to put besides the one and "Läuft [gerade]" might be it. Although  "läuft" on its own sounds a bit clunky...

Comment: a) Manchmal läuft gerade, manchmal geht schief. Wie wäre es mit "jetzt"? b) I'd say "showing" somehow parallels the meaning of "watching" in this context (cp "zur Schau stellen"), as does "playing". As German has no present progressive participle, the translation naturally suffers. "spielt" is stylistically poor, but a self-reflexive word (i.e. "es spielt sich ab") might best convey the intended Grammar (poor alas, because "spielt" is primarily transitive). Compär "lädt". c) "läuft" rather translates "running", but it works very well idiomatically, anyhow.